# ASP.NET Radio button checked changed event not firing for first radio button

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

I am facing an issue where the checked changed event of the first radio button is not firing. I enabled `ViewState` but still the issue persists. Please see below code:

```
<span class="pull-right text-right">
    <label class="inline radio">
        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdoViewAll" CausesValidation="false" GroupName="Filter" Text="View All" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" Checked="true" />
    </label>
    <label class="inline radio">
        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdoViewCurrent" CausesValidation="false" GroupName="Filter" Text="View Current" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </label>
    <label class="inline radio">
        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdoViewFuture" CausesValidation="false" GroupName="Filter" Text="View Future" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </label>
</span>
```

And I am setting the checked changed event on `Page_Init` as below:

```
public void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.rdoViewAll.CheckedChanged += (s, a) =>
    {
        RebindTerms();
    };
    this.rdoViewFuture.CheckedChanged += (s, a) =>
    {
        RebindTerms();
    };
    this.rdoViewCurrent.CheckedChanged += (s, a) =>
    {
        RebindTerms();
    };
}
```

One thing I noticed is when I remove the `Checked="true"` property on the first radio button the `CheckedChanged` event fires successfully. However, I need the first radio button to be checked by default on page load.

Comment: I believe you already knew that you can't uncheck a RadioButton in a group without checking another one. With that, the CheckedChanged event will only trigger to the remaining uncheck RadioButton and not the RadioButton which is already checked so in your  case, rdoViewAll is your default the event will only trigger for rdoViewFuture and rdoViewCurrent.

Comment: I suggest you use Click event instead.

Comment: @Dr.Stitch - The RadioButton has no Click event that can be handled in code-behind.

Comment: yes, what i'm suggesting is a javascript click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leave `Checked="false"` for all the RadioButtons initially, and set the selected button with client code:

```
private RadioButton selectedRadioButton;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selectedRadioButton = rdoViewAll;

    if (rdoViewCurrent.Checked)
    {
        selectedRadioButton = rdoViewCurrent;
    }

    if (rdoViewFuture.Checked)
    {
        selectedRadioButton = rdoViewFuture;
    }

    rdoViewAll.Checked = false;
    rdoViewCurrent.Checked = false;
    rdoViewFuture.Checked = false;

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "InitRadio", string.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').checked = true;", selectedRadioButton.ClientID), true);
}
```

Clicking on any RadioButton will always trigger the `CheckedChanged` event. The RadioButton that is actually selected is stored in `selectedRadioButton`, if you need it in other parts of the server code.

Comment: Hi there again, I have a problem now with above code. It does not work when the first radio button is selected for a second time after few postbacks. Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: I modified my answer to trigger the event any time you click on a RadioButton, even if it is already selected.